# Webpack / npm - How to install jquery, bootstrap and boostrap-tables

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-6, laravel-7, webpack-4

I have a project with laravel7 using blade templates, and at the moment I am using webpack and I get a compilation error that I show at the end of the post.

**File webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js([
    'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/popper/popper.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/boostrap-table/bootstrap-table.min.js',
    'resources/assets/vendor/boostrap-table/bootstrap-table-es-ES.min.js',
], 'public/js/app.js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/app.css');
```

**File app.js**

```
    require('./bootstrap');
```

**File app.scss**

```
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "../vendor/boostrap-table/bootstrap-table.min.css";
@import '../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
@import "style";


@import "../vendor/twitter-boostrap/bootstrap.css";
@import "../vendor/twitter-boostrap/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css";
```

These last two lines are the ones that are giving me a failure when doing an npm run watch
The error I get is this

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/vendor/twitter-boostrap/bootstrap.css 
(./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??
postcss0!./resources/assets/vendor/twitter-boostrap/bootstrap.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot' in 
'C:\Apache24\htdocs\laravel\resources\assets\vendor\twitter-boostrap'
```

Comment: First try to exclude second load of bootstrap.css file (in app.scss).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely mix is causing the error because the url path for the font is not absolute. You should try this.

```
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/app.css')
.options({
    processCssUrls: false
});
```

More info here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#url-processing